# Extracting data from nested Python dictionaries

Tags: python, json, pandas, loops, dictionary

I know there are some similar posts here, however I've tried each solution and none of them work for my scenario.

I have a complicated dictionary, full of lists and other dictionaries. Which looks like this:

```
data = {'key1': 'value1',
 'key2': 'value2',
 'key3': 'value3',
 'results': [{'id': 'id1_value',
   'label1': 'label1_value',
   'label2': 'label2_value',
   'fields': {'field1': 'field1_value',
    'field2': 'field2_value',
    'field3': 'field3_value'},
   'label3': 'label3_value',
   'label4': 'label4'},
 {'id': 'id2_value',
   'label1': 'label1_value',
   'label2': 'label2_value',
   'fields': {'field1': 'field1_value',
    'field2': 'field2_value',
    'field3': 'field3_value'},
   'label3': 'label3_value',
   'label4': 'label4'}]}
```

I want to create a dataframe that extracts certain values from this dict. Specifically, I want to have the following:

| id | label2 | field2 | field3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | label2_value | field2_value | field3_value |
| id2 | label2_value | field2_value | field3_value |

I've tried creating a blank list, then looping through the data structure, saving the various elements I want to variables, then appending them to my list. Finally creating a df from the list. I've used the following code:

```
mylist = []

data_results = data['results']
for x in data_results:
    id = data_results['id']
    label2 = data_results['label2']
    fields = x['fields']
    for x in fields:
        field2 = fields['field2']
        field3 = fields['field3']
    mylist.append([label2,body,byline])
pd.DataFrame(mylist)
```

However it doesn't work, I get various errors (e.g. "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str") or I get just one element but not the others.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: `data_results` is a list of dictionaries, so `data_results['id']` will fail. You should use `x` in your for loop as `id = x['id']` and so on.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't appear to define either "body" or "byline", and (as @alexis pointed out below), reusing variable names like "x" is a recipe for trouble....

and your inner loop doesn't actually use "x", which seems like a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch away from generic variable names like `x`, you may find it easier to keep track of where in your structure you are looking:

```
for result in data['results']:
    id_ = result['id']
    label2 = result['label2']
    fields = result['fields']  # Intermediate variable (note: no loop)
    field2 = fields['field2']
    field3 = fields['field3']
    mylist.append([id_, label2, field2, field3])
```

You get the idea. (Also in your code, you used `x` for two different purposes which will surely lead to surprises.)

If your actual structure doesn't get much deeper, you might actually find it simpler to write

```
...
    field2 = result['fields']['field2']
```

which shows the path to this value, instead of using the intermediate variable. But that's a matter of taste.

Comment: did the trick! Thanks. Think I was staring at this one for too long. Thanks for the help.